# baseurl not working for YII2

Tags: php, yii2

```
<?=Yii::$app->request->baseUrl?>
```

The Code mentioned above is not working for me n YII2 Framework however if I uses `var_dump` to check , it returns Empty String

Comment: have you tried  `\Yii::$app->request->getBaseUrl()` ?

Comment: i think you start new yii2 project, composer update  or you change composer.json stablity anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<?= \Yii::$app->request->url; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Url](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-url.html) helper instead?

```
<?php

    use yii\helpers\Url;

    // Relative base url 
    echo Url::base();

    // Absolute base url
    echo Url::base(true)

?>
```

Or if it's the home URL you're after...

```
<?php

    use yii\helpers\Url;

    // Relative base url 
    echo Url::home();

    // Absolute base url
    echo Url::home(true)

?>
```